# Can you specify a word separator for variables in listings?

Tags: listings, r

Depending on the language specified, the listings package may or may not bold keywords inside of variable names.

Python is fine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} 
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
    sum_of_the_values = sum(vals)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Python latex output]

But R is not fine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} 
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
    sum.of.the.values = sum(vals)
    sum_of_the_values = sum(vals)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: R latex output]

Can you specify a word separator character? Could I use R's dot-separated variables (`sum.of.the.values`)?

Comment: Well, I can't find anything in the `lstlang<n>.sty` files on this....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `listings` package categorizes characters in three ways: *letter*, *digit*, and *other*. The `R` language for `listings`, whose definition can be found in [`lstdvrs.dtx`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx),
is defined in such a way as to treat periods as *other*:

```
\lst@definelanguage{R}%
   %...
   alsoother={._$},%
   %...
  }%
```

However, as I understand it, in R, a period (`.`) [can be used in identifiers](http://www.johndcook.com/R_language_for_programmers.html#variable) in a way similar to how an underscore would be used in many other languages: as a name separator.

In that case, `listings` should be told to treat the period character, not as *other*, but as *letter*. Strings such as `sum.of.letter.values` will then be treated as a single identifier, and the `sum` substring in this particular string will no longer get (incorrectly) highlighted as an R keyword.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} 
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R,alsoletter=.]
    sum.of.the.values = sum(vals)
    sum_of_the_values = sum(vals)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, `alsoletter` is what I was looking for. A side effect is that builtin keywords like `na.rm` have to be respecified, as `na` and `rm` are different entries in [lstdvrs.dtx](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx).

Comment: @ajnisbet Yes, you're right. My approach will cause `na.rm` to be treated as a single identifier. You may have to redefine such keywords, but I can't think of a better approach.